# Solidify Material Offset won't show up in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I'm trying to make a stick figure character, so I decided to have a white orb with black Material Offset for the head. However, the white material on the orb disappears in viewport rendered shading, leaving the entire orb black. However, it reappears in material preview. This also only happens in Cycles. Any idea as to why that could be?

Comment: can you share some pictures to better explain the problem?

Comment: Hi, Graham, Not without  more details.. or at least we can only guess. Perhaps easiest to share the faulty head in a .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I'm new to BSE, how do I send pictures?